# Can't add an array of numbers in AdminJS

Tags: adminjs

In a resourse I have property that should be an array of numbers.
`properties: { firstDownAttempts: { type: 'number', isArray: true, }, },`
In AdminJS when I create a new object I add two items like this:
[image]

After this I can log these items in "before" hook. The values look like:
`'firstDownAttempts.0': '33', 'firstDownAttempts.1': '22',`

But Prisma returns the error where I can see payload with my property `firstDownAttempts: NaN`

It works well when I add only one item, but I need two.

Is this an AdminJS bug, or I do something wrong? Can I somehow avoid it?

I use AdminJS with Nest.js. @adminjs/nestjs 5.1.0
AdminJS version 6.8.4

I tried to play with props of my property, like specifying type or not. Also I tried to put an array in "before" hook, but it doesn't work.